# Calculate the number of each variable where each variable =1

Tags: sas

Could you help to calculate the number of each variable where each variable =1? I posted how can I calculate the missing number here. Hopefully, it is the similar way. Thanks in advance.

```
/*y00*/
%let list0=OCALZHMR OCARTERY OCARTH  OCCHD OCDIABTS OCHBP OCMENTAL OCMYOCAR
          OCOTHART OCPSYCH OCSTROKE;

/*y01 and y02*/
%let list1=D_CFAIL D_CHD D_HBP D_MYOCAR D_OTHHRT  D_PSYCH D_RHYTHM D_STROKE 
       D_VALVE OCALZHMR OCARTERY OCARTH  OCCHD OCDIABTS OCHBP OCMENTAL OCMYOCAR 
       OCOTHART  OCPSYCH OCSTROKE;


proc means data=cohort00 nmiss noprint;
     var &list0; 
     output out=y2000_nmiss(drop=_:) nmiss= ;
run;

proc means data=cohort01 nmiss noprint;
     var &list1; 
     output out=y2001_nmiss(drop=_:) nmiss= ;
run;

data y2000_nmiss;
 set y2000_nmiss;
 j=1;
run;

data y2001_nmiss;
 set y2001_nmiss;
 j=1;
run;

proc transpose data=y2000_nmiss out=long0(rename=(COL1=Y2000 _name_=VAR));
     by j;
run;
proc transpose data=y2001_nmiss out=long1(rename=(COL1=Y2001 _name_=VAR));
     by j;
run;

data ATC_missing;
  merge long0 long1;
  by VAR;
  drop j;
run;
```

Here is the part of output table for the number of missing :

```
   VARS  Y2000   Y2001  Y2002
OCDIABTS    0     1        0
OCHBP       0     0        0
OCMENTAL   17    18       10
OCMYOCAR    0     0        0
OCOTHART    0     0     4758
OCOTHHRT    .     .        .
OCPSYCH     0     0        0
```

Comment: Please include a properly-formatted sample of your **expected output** so folks understand the results you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
%let list1=Width Length Depth;

data work.is_even / view=work.is_even;
set sashelp.lake;
   array vars {*} &list1 ;
   drop i;
   do i=1 to dim(vars);
       if mod(round(vars(i), 1),2)  = 0 /* would be VARS(I)=1 for your case */
        then vars(i)=1;
   else vars(i)=.;
   end;
run;

proc means data=work.is_even n;
run;
```

First I create a datastep view work.is_even (view in order to avoid a full copy of data) that manipulates the data in the way I need.
Here it overrides the original value of variables (not in original data, just in that view) by 1 if the rounded value is even, by null if it's odd.
Then, just count the nonmissing values (N statistic in PROC MEANS).

Comment: The PROC FREQ would be less efficient - would need to pass the data separately for each variable to get correct results. E.g. proc freq data=xxx;table var1;where var1=1;run;   proc freq data=xxx;table var2;where var2=1;run;

Comment: Thanks Vasja and Ajay. Vasja, you created the variables only have two levels which just change nmiss to n for my previous code. but my variables have **several levels**. I used **proc sql** but not efficient way.Thanks again!

Comment: I thought you're interested in counts of one specific value. If you interested in all levels, then PROC FREQ is indeed the right one, sorry for refusing it. It also can count the missing values. Here combined with ODS features: ods trace on;
ods select OneWayFreqs;
ods output OneWayFreqs=work.freqs;
proc freq data=sashelp.class;
tables _all_ / nocum nopercent;
output out=freqs ;
run;
ods trace off;

Comment: I have several levels, but only need the frequency of the variables either "missing" or "=1". I have 10 years data set and part of all variables each year need the two level ("missing" or "=1") frequency.